# Vue.js 2 & Axios Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I worked with this "issue" before but I don't really remember how to get properly the results. I am using Vue 2 to load some data in variables that I can load in the HTML side:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.axios = require('axios');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        operaciones: [],
        sopts: []
    },
    created: function() {
        this.loadOperationTypes();
        console.log(this.operaciones); <-- SC
    },
    methods: {
        loadOperationTypes: function() {
            axios.post('/api/operaciones')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data); <-- FC
                this.operaciones = response.data
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.operaciones = error;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

If I write `console.log(response.data)` in the Axios function scope (FC) it  prints:

[image]

But if I write `console.log(response.data)` in the `created_ function() {}` scope, it prints:

[image]

I already tried to use this like:

```
axios.post('/api/operaciones')
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    app.operaciones = response.data
})
```

And

```
var $this = this;
axios.post('/api/operaciones')
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    $this.operaciones = response.data
})
```

But is the same, any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a separate issue from scope. Any of the solutions you tried in your question will work to properly set `this.operaciones`. The issue is that you are dealing with an asynchronous operation.

The line

```
console.log(this.operaciones);
```

in `created` will **always** log an empty array. That is because `loadOperationTypes` performs a asynchronous operation; meaning it takes *time*.

You seem to be expecting that everything in `loadOperationTypes` will complete before the `console.log` is executed, but that is not the case. `loadOperationTypes` will initiate the `post` to the server, and then the code will continue and execute the `console.log`.

Once a response is received from the server *at a later point in time*, then `operaciones` is populated with the response.

```js
console.clear()

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        operaciones: [],
        sopts: []
    },
    created: function() {
        this.loadOperationTypes();
        console.log("THIS WILL ALWAYS BE AN EMPTY ARRAY", this.operaciones);
    },
    methods: {
        loadOperationTypes: function() {
            axios.post('https://httpbin.org/post', ["some", "data"])
            .then(response => {
                console.log("THIS SHOULD HAVE DATA", response.data.json);
                this.operaciones = response.data.json
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.operaciones = error;
            });
        }
    },
    watch: {
      operaciones(newVal){
        console.log("THIS WILL HAVE DATA WHEN operaciones IS POPULATED", newVal)
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I completely forgot, I checked now with the Vue Inspector and all the information seems to be there. Thank you.